# vb.net read json response from server

Tags: json, vb.net

I am new to consuming web services. I have created a console app that requests and receives json formatted data from the web server. Based on an example from online(cannot find site now)

JSON Response from server. actual data different

```
{
    "message": {
        "campus": {
            "env": "test",
            "key_id": "AAAABBBBBCCCCDDD",
             "contractSending": [
                {
                   "hash":"EEEEFFFFGGGG",
                   "origin": "11111"
                }
            ],
            "contractReceiving": []
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried several solutions with no success. This is the cleanest example I found that did not require purchasing 3rd party software.

```
Imports System.Net
Imports System.Web.Script.Serialization
Module Module1
    Sub Main()
        Dim url As String = String.Format("localhost/api/orders/access/?campus={0}&pin={1}", "1111", "222222")
        Using client As New WebClient()
            'Get server response
            Dim jsonString As String = client.DownloadString(url)
            Dim campusInfo As CampusMessage = (New JavaScriptSerializer()).Deserialize(Of CampusMessage)(jsonString)
        End Using
    End Sub

    Public Class CampusMessage
        Public Property messsage As Campus
    End Class

    Public Class Campus
        Public Property env As String
        Public Property key_id As String
        Public Property contractSending As ContractSending
    End Class

    Public Class ContractSending
        Public Property hash As String
        Public Property origin As String
    End Class

    Public Class ContractReceiving
        Public Property hash As String
        Public Property origin As String
    End Class

End Module
```

I expected the Campus message class and subs to have data. the VB watch window reports null exception.

Comment: I can't exactly look at your thing now and give a proper answer, but you can check my answers on JSON topics, there's at least a hint for you if not a solution.

Comment: Have a play with http://QuickType.io, and enable the "break on thrown" for all CLR exceptions - your program will pause as soon as you get an exception

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For start, your JSON is incorrect.

```
"origin": "11111", 'that comma there shouldn't be there as there are no more elements after it
```

And you didn't properly write the classes.
Use the tools to make them automatically or use some JSON visualizers so you can step trough and track it more easily and that way write it out properly.

After that it works fine.

```
Public Class CampusMessage
    Public Property message As Message
End Class

Public Class Message
    Public Property campus As Campus
End Class

Public Class Campus
    Public Property env As String
    Public Property key_id As String
    Public Property contractSending As ContractSending()
    Public Property contractReceiving As Object()
End Class

Public Class ContractSending
    Public Property hash As String
    Public Property origin As String
End Class
```

[] marks and array, so you have to make your dataholder an array also, like ContractSending() instead of ContractSending

Comment: One of the tools you mention is on the Edit menu in Visual Studio. Paste Special -> Paste JSON Classes.

Comment: OK, the comma thing was my fault when trying to simplify a much longer JSON string. The rest points to a bad example. I will test your suggestions and mark as correct answer or let you know any issues remaining. Edited JSON example to remove the extra comma's

Comment: @Mary Indeed, it only exists if you have installed ASP.Net and Web Developer tools though.

Comment: @Mary I tried the Paste Special and it did a fair job. However it put the parentheses in the wrong place.i.e Public Property contractSending() As Contractsending rather than Public Property contractSending As Contractsending()

Comment: @MarkClark That is the correct position for the parentheses. It is variable array as type. Look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/arrays/ and notice that every array is declared variableName() As Type.

Comment: @Mary They both work the same yes, but I read that Variable Type(Array) is preferred syntax (over Variable(Array) Type) and it also mirrors other languages. Besides Variable only having a name and not a number beside is looks more natural to me. I don't have 30 variables of 1 but 1 of 30.

Comment: @Mary For example here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/arrays/how-to-initialize-an-array-variable microsoft says the other way is preferred. They sure are consistent...

Comment: @CruleD Consistent? I assume that is tongue in cheek. ;~) I checked several VB docs and they all seem to use `variableName() As Type.` I guess we need to complain to MS that their generated code is not the preferred method. I strongly agree that doing it the C# way is good for switching back and forth.

Comment: @Mary I'll put it this way, VS didn't like the parenthesis there. Thru a compiler error with them there.

Comment: @MarkClark Tried it, No compile error. This is Microsoft generated code.

Comment: @Mary I'm rusty on VB.NET. All I know is I put the generated code in my VB console app and it would not compile without moving the parenthesis. Maybe it has something to do with with my VS 2017 install being done with C# as the primary language since CruleD comments he/she feels it works both ways.